# Updating a timer label in another form with info from a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, timer, label

Ok i think i can accurately ask this question after going over everything again. I am trying to update a timer countdown label in another form. The label in form 2 displays the timer added in form 1 from a cell selected in a datagridview. So far i can increase and decrease the amount of time added to the dgv as well as update and remove the rows themselves. My issue is that although i can display the time in a cell in another form i cant seem to get it to count down once form 2 appears. I managed to confirm that the timer in form 2 is working its just the label im having trouble with. This is what ive tried so far in form 2 to get it to count down but nothing seems to be working. Im new to programming so sorry if my tech vocabulary is lacking.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    TimeSpan TotalTimeLeft;
    TimeSpan AdditionalTime;
    DateTime StartTime;
    DateTime WhenTimesUpTime;
    public int TotalHours;
    public int TotalMinutes;
    public int TotalSeconds;
    public int RemainingSeconds;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.timer1.Start();
        form2.TimerDisplay2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // creat a variable to hold an int value to create new rows and connect it to the datagridview.
        //Adds a row
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = PasswordText.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = TimerDisplay.Text;
        // clears textbox after data is entered
        PasswordText.Clear();
        //resets label text back to default
        TimerDisplay.Text = "" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalHours) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalMinutes) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", RemainingSeconds);
        //Resets Time increase back to 0
        AdditionalTime = new TimeSpan();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Removes a row
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            if (!row.IsNewRow) dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Updates info
        DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        newDataRow.Cells[0].Value = PasswordText.Text;
        newDataRow.Cells[1].Value = TimerDisplay.Text;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Increases time by set amount
        // Add time button
        AddTimeMinutes(5);
        
        
    }
    private void AddTimeMinutes(int MinutesToAdd)
    {
        AdditionalTime = AdditionalTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(MinutesToAdd));
        //Tio: Substract the current time from when the time will be up as a timespan
        
        // Calculate total hours

        TotalHours = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalHours;

        //Tio: Calculate Total minutes and save to an integer.

         //int TotalMinutes = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalMinutes;
        TotalMinutes = (int)AdditionalTime.Minutes;

        //Tio: Calculate remaining seconds after the total minutes to display along with the minutes remaining.

        //TotalSeconds = (int)AdditionalTime.Seconds;

        int RemainingSeconds = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalSeconds - ((int)TotalMinutes * 60) - ((int)TotalHours * 3600);

        //Tio: Display the time left in minutes and seconds.
        //MessageBox.Show("Total Hours:" + TotalHours.ToString() + " Total Minutes:" + TotalMinutes.ToString() + " Total Seconds:" + TotalSeconds.ToString());

        TimerDisplay.Text = "" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalHours) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalMinutes) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", RemainingSeconds);

        
     
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Decrease time button
        AddTimeMinutes(-5);
    }
}

 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    TimeSpan TotalTimeLeft;
    TimeSpan AdditionalTime;
    DateTime StartTime;
    DateTime WhenTimesUpTime;
    public int TotalHours;
    public int TotalMinutes;
    public int TotalSeconds;
    public int RemainingSeconds;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TotalHours > 0)
        {
            // Display the new time left
            // by updating the Time Left label.
            TotalHours = TotalHours - 1;
            TimerDisplay2.Text = TotalHours + "" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalHours);
        }
        else if (TotalMinutes > 0)
        {
            // If the user ran out of time, stop the timer, show
            // a MessageBox, and fill in the answers.
            TotalMinutes = TotalMinutes - 1;
            TimerDisplay2.Text = TotalMinutes + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalMinutes);
        }
        else if (RemainingSeconds > 0)
        {
            RemainingSeconds = RemainingSeconds - 1;
            TimerDisplay2.Text = RemainingSeconds + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", RemainingSeconds);
        }

        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
    public void AddTimeMinutes(int MinutesToAdd)
    {
        AdditionalTime = AdditionalTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(MinutesToAdd));
        //Tio: Substract the current time from when the time will be up as a timespan

        // Calculate total hours

        TotalHours = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalHours;

        //Tio: Calculate Total minutes and save to an integer.

        //int TotalMinutes = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalMinutes;
        TotalMinutes = (int)AdditionalTime.Minutes;

        //Tio: Calculate remaining seconds after the total minutes to display along with the minutes remaining.

        //TotalSeconds = (int)AdditionalTime.Seconds;

        int RemainingSeconds = (int)AdditionalTime.TotalSeconds - ((int)TotalMinutes * 60) - ((int)TotalHours * 3600);

        //Tio: Display the time left in minutes and seconds.
        //MessageBox.Show("Total Hours:" + TotalHours.ToString() + " Total Minutes:" + TotalMinutes.ToString() + " Total Seconds:" + TotalSeconds.ToString());

        TimerDisplay2.Text = "" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalHours) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", TotalMinutes) + ":" + String.Format("{0,2:d2}", RemainingSeconds);



    }
}
```

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ He has Form2 code in his post: `public partial class Form2 : Form`. It's about half way down the posted code base.

Comment: @RyanWilson hahah, maybe I should have scrolled a little further down. Anyways, thanks for the find, I've removed my comment.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ No worries. :P

Comment: You should look at passing `Form1` timer into `Form2` instance when it's created and assign that object to a `readonly` var that you then can use in your `Form2` class.

Comment: Where in `Form2` are the variables `TotalHours`, `TotalMinutes` and `TotalSeconds` initialized? I assume this important info is missing for a reason?

Comment: The `timer1_Tick` event in `form2` is not going to work as you expect. I assume this is where you want to “count-down” the time in the label `TimerDisplay2`. It is unknown what the timers “interval” is nor is it known what the “initial” values are for the variables used in the tick event… TotalHours, Minutes and seconds. Even if we have these values, the code is not going to work as a “count-down” timer. Example…

Comment: Let’s assume the timer’s interval is set to 1000… i.e. 1 second. This would mean that the timer’s “Tick” event will get fired once every second. Let us also assume the initial values for TotalHours, totalMinutes and TotalSeconds are all set to five (5).

Comment: Now when form2 is initialized, the timer is started. After one (1) second has passed the timers “Tick” event fires… in the event, the first check is made for total hours… `if (TotalHours > 0) …` which will be `true` since 5 > 0. The code then decrements total hours by 1, making TotalHours = 4. …?  This is odd since in reality only 1 second has passed yet the code removed 1 hour. This is confusing and from what I can see will not work as you are expecting.

Comment: Uh lets see for your first inquiry i copied a bunch of code into form 2 in the hopes it would lead me to the right answer in getting the label timer to activate so its probably unnecessary and ill probably have to remove it. 

Second the timers interval is set to the standard 1000 for it to count down every second. The initial values for the amount of time were to be imported in from the datagridview in form one. So if i put in 10 minutes into a cell and clicked on it, that info would be transferred over to the label in form 2. But i suppose im having difficulty translating that

Comment: into a form the timer can read and countdown from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do my best to make this simple. Your question has two (2) questions… i.e. the countdown timer not working and the label on the other form is not updating. Even though, the countdown is what the label displays on the other form, the current code you have has no way of updating this label.

For the label on the other form, a simple solution is to “pass” that label to `Form2` via its constructor. Like:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(lblForm1CountDown);
```

Then in `Form2`, create a `Label` `parentCDLabel` then assign this label to the passed in `Label` in the constructor. Something like…

```
Label parentCDLabel;

public Form2(Label pCDLabel) {
  InitializeComponent();
  parentCDLabel = pCDLabel;
   …..
}
```

Now, `Form2` has access to `Form1`’s label and we can update it when we update the label on `Form2`.

That takes care of 1 issue.

Next is the count down timer. There are numerous ways you can do this, however, managing the count downs Hours, Minutes and Seconds “MANUALLY” is the wrong approach. It can certainly be done, however, there are easier and more reliable ways to achieve this “count down.”

The main point is when dealing with ”time” values, then use a “time” type object, like the `TimeSpan`. Your current code uses multiple `TimeSpan` objects, and this not only complicates things, but it is unnecessary. You can make a timer count down display with one (1) `Timer` object and one `TimeSpan` object.

I will assume from the `form1` `CellDoubleClick` event that this is where you would get the “Total Time” to count down. This has been unclear to me; however, it is important. If we want to count down to zero… what time span value do we start with? In the current posted code, I am guessing this starting “Total Time” to count down is coming from the cell the user “double” clicked.

The point here, is that “whatever and however” this starting “Total Time” is acquired… `form2` is NEVER given this important starting info. Example, lets say that the user double clicked a cell where the `TimeSpan` was `TimeSpan(0, 1, 15)` … a span of 1 minute and 15 seconds. This is what we want to start the count down with. `Form2` is going to need to KNOW this to know where to start the countdown from. The current code does not pass this important info to `form2` and it should.

Given this, it appears we need to pass another parameter to `From2`. This would be a `TimeSpan` object and would represent what time span value we want to start the count down with. Below is an example of `form1` passing this value to `form2`. Since it unclear how the code is getting this value, I simply supplied a new `TimeSpan` object. Passing a starting value of 1 minute and 30 seconds may look like…

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30), lblForm1CountDown);
```

Then in `Form2`  create a `TimeSpan` object and assign it to the passed in `TimeSpan` object.….

```
TimeSpan totalTime;

public Form2(TimeSpan tTime, Label pCDLabel) {
  InitializeComponent();
  totalTime = tTime;
  parentCDLabel = pCDLabel;
}
```

Now `Form2` has all the info it needs to start the countdown timer. It has a starting countdown value and it has form1’s label to update when the countdown changes. To help, `form2` is going to use a `Timer` that fires once every second. When it fires, the idea is to subtract 1 second from the starting `TimeSpan` value, update the labels and that is it. Checking the hours, minutes and seconds is unnecessary. We continue this every second until the `TimeSpan` value reaches zero (0). At which point, time has run out.

Putting all this together… `Form1` would get the starting `TimeSpan` value and the label and pass those to `form2` this is shown above. In `Form2` a `Timer` is created to fire every second. Also, two `TimeSpan` objects are used. `totalTime` is the passed in starting time span and `timeLeft` is used to show the amount of time left. It is unnecessary to use two variables here and `totalTime` is simply used to let the user know at any point how much time they started with. The `timeLeft` variable will obviously be “updated” every second. When the form initializes… we wire up the timers tick event and set an interval of 1 second, then on the load we start the timer.

```
TimeSpan totalTime;
TimeSpan timeLeft;
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
Label parentCDLabel;
StringBuilder sb;

public Form2(TimeSpan tTime, Label pCDLabel) {
  InitializeComponent();
  timeLeft = tTime;
  totalTime = tTime;
  parentCDLabel = pCDLabel;
  timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
  timer1.Interval = 1000;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Finally, the `timer1_Tick` event. When fired, we simply subtract one (1) second from `timeLeft` update the labels on both forms, then finally a check to see if the time has run out.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timeLeft = timeLeft.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine("Total time: " + totalTime.Hours + ":" + totalTime.Minutes + ":" + totalTime.Seconds);
  sb.AppendLine(" Time left: " + timeLeft.Hours + ":" + timeLeft.Minutes + ":" + timeLeft.Seconds);
  lblCountDown.Text = sb.ToString();
  parentCDLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
  if (timeLeft.Ticks <= 0) {
    timer1.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("Time has run out!");
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: It did help but unfortunately my skills still arent up to par with probably something an amateur could piece together so i wasnt able to make it work. Luckily my uncle whos a programmer helped me out even if i wanted to try and figure it out myself and we got it to work. Thank you everyone that helped me out. Hopefully i can get better at this.

Comment: @Kevin Cobb Jr. I am glad you got it working. Like most disciplines, it can be challenging to get started. Don’t give up. You are doing just fine. I sense frustration, and sympathize more, I could not. Keep chugging away and you will do fine. Good luck.